# How to open a pdf in a specific page via python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdfplumber

As a part of my program I was trying to, as the title suggests, open a pdf file in a web browser on a specific page so reading the contents of that pdf page and printing it via pdfplumber or PyPDF2 won't really do.

I tried searching up methods to do so but to no avail, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can, alternatively or in addition, set the value inside the PDF file itself with `cpdf -open-at-page 9 in.pdf -o out.pdf`. But again, the browser may choose to ignore this information. You must experiment.

Comment: K J's comment answered my question but I'm still interested in john's method but I'm confused about how I should go about to implement this. Tia